# Transfer .cn domain to another registrar

Tags: domain-registration, domain-transfer

I have to transfer domains hosted by a deficient local ISP in China. Can I transfer my domain registration without my current ISP's cooperation?

Comment: If your registrar is uncooperative, there is not much you can do. You may be able to file a complaint with the entity that handles the ccTLD or gTLD assignments. Otherwise, maybe any new registrar can help though that may be difficult. I am sure that many registrars deal with this everyday. I would assume that GoDaddy can give pointers and help you to transfer the site. They are large enough and the have some real experts though they are not generally answering the phone. You may have to ask for a supervisor if you contact any registrar. Be patient and explain your issue carefully.

Answer (score 2):

.cn domain transfers generally work about the same as transfers of any other domain name. You obtain an authorization code from the old registrar, and have the domain unlocked. Then you provide the authorization code to the new registrar and wait up to 5 days.

There is a restriction that .cn domain names registered with a registrar in China cannot be transferred to a registrar outside China, and vice versa. So if your current registrar is a Chinese company, you can only transfer to another Chinese registrar.

Under [CNNIC rules](http://www1.cnnic.cn/PublicS/fwzx/cnymfaq/201210/t20121008_36615.htm#8), the old registrar can take up to three days to give you the authorization code to transfer the domain, but in practice this should happen within minutes. Check with the old registrar to confirm what they may require to initiate the transfer process, such as submitting proof of identity.

If the old registrar is refusing to give you an authorization code, I would suggest contacting CNNIC directly for advice, as this is a very unusual situation. I was not able to find any mentions on the Internet of anyone who had suffered it.